# What happened to this Bitcoin transaction? Block fee lost?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees

I'm writing a bitcoin blockchain indexer. I've indexed every block hash and now I'm working on indexing each transaction in each block.

I've been finding some weird stuff here and there and I don't understand this one (there are a few others just like this):

What happened to the Bitcoin? It appears that the block fee was "lost"?

txid: ee40c94cc60cb3b0b59b86c2dec1c1187c4cc357c86b173fd0e8b8d4f925e5a0

[image: tx]

Comment: What do you mean lost

Comment: That's what I am asking lol. Look at the screenshot. 

It shows and unknown transaction worth nothing. 

What happened to the fee?

Comment: I think you are confused by how transactions work. On the right it's tx outputs. On the left transaction input (confusingly displaying an address, which isn't present in a tx input). The fee is the left over of the sum of tx outputs' amounts minus the sum of tx inputs' amounts.

Answer (score 0):

The first output is an [OP_RETURN](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=OP_RETURN) output whose content is:

Raw Hex:
`5035e332014086d1` `6c5a07b4d277b5f4`
`95c85fd7c20167cd` `31029dac6f9293fc`
`0b7988032d44b0d3` `159bb0f423de`

Which [Blockchair.com displays as](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/ee40c94cc60cb3b0b59b86c2dec1c1187c4cc357c86b173fd0e8b8d4f925e5a0)  "Decoded:" `P52@lZw_g1oy-D#`

(the other output is change)

---

> What happened to the fee?

That is the difference between the input and the change output. The OP_RETURN output doesn't affect this because it has a monetary value of zero.

Comment: Ok I see, so some code changes need to be made to filter this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Just one follow-up, if I wanted to decode this, is it UTF-8?

Comment: OP_RETURN can be followed by up to 80 bytes of data in any encoding chosen by the transaction creator. In this case it isn't valid UTF-8 - I don't know why blockchair.com decoded it the way it did. I guess Blockchair makes an assumption. See "Raw Tx" on that page for exact data values.